# Simplify a Boole function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, boolean-computation

I have a very long polynomial expression (which we can call here $f(x,y,z,\zeta)$). The coefficient have this object appearing a lot:

```
Boole[Im[\[ScriptH][y]] != 0 || 1/2 + Re[\[ScriptH][y]] < 1 || 
Re[\[ScriptH][y]] > 1]
```

I would like to see if there is any way of forcing Mathematica to simplify this element, knowing that

1. Im[[ScriptH][y]] = 0 (first condition FALSE)
2. Re[[ScriptH][y]] < 1 (third condition FALSE)

I have tried writing:

```
Assuming[Im[\[ScriptH][y]]==0,f[x,y,z,\[Zeta]]]
```

but it does not seem to work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `Simplify[
 Boole[Im[\[ScriptH][y]] != 0 || 1/2 + Re[\[ScriptH][y]] < 1 || 
   Re[\[ScriptH][y]] > 1],
 {Im[\[ScriptH][y]] == 0, Re[\[ScriptH][y]] < 1}
 ]`

Answer (score 2):

try simplifying:

```
Assuming[Im[\[ScriptH][y]]==0, f[x,y,z,\[Zeta]] // FullSimplify]
```